# Constant in Sobolev embedding theorem on the cube

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces

Let $Y$ be a unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Sobolev embedding theorem says that in the case $N=4$ one has the following embedding:
\begin{equation} 
H^2(Y)\text{ is embedded continuously into }L^p(Y)\text{ provided }p<\infty.
\end{equation}
This is a peculiarity of the dimension $N=4$, for other dimensions there exists the largest value of $p$, for which the above embedding holds (namely, $p=2N/(N-4)$ as $N>4$,  $p=\infty$ as $N=2,3$).

**Question: is it possible to compute (or, at least, to estimate it *from below*) the norm of the above embedding**, i.e. the smallest constant $C_p$ for which
$$
\|u\|_{L^p(Y)} < C_p \|u\|_{H^2(Y)},  \forall f\in H^2(Y)
$$
holds. Recall, that Y is a unit cube, so quite simple domain.

Comment: It should be possible to track the steps of the standard embedding theorem on the unit cube. Another possibility is to look into papers from people doing computer-based existence/enclosure results for pdes: Plum, Nakao.